# Variable losing stored value

Tags: java, variables

In the code below, XPos keeps changing values without any action take on it by my code.

```
public class JTwinPreviewButtons {
    static PreviewPanel previewPanel;
    static EditorPanel editorPanel;
    ArrayList<JTwinPreviewButtons> subButtons = new ArrayList<JTwinPreviewButtons>();
    private static int overallYPos = 0;
    Item item;
    JButton plusButton;
    JButton itemButton;
    private boolean isPlus;
    private boolean shown;
    private int YPos;
    private int XPos;

    public JTwinPreviewButtons(Item someItem, int itemNum) {
        plusButton = new JButton("-");
        itemButton = new JButton(someItem.getName());
        item = someItem;
        isPlus = false;
        shown = true;
        System.out.println("Item Number: "+itemNum);
        XPos = (itemNum * 15) + 25;
        System.out.println(XPos); //XPos == 70
        if (previewPanel!=null) {
            if (itemNum == 0) {
                previewPanel.addTopButton(this);
            }
            previewPanel.refresh();   //printed inside here XPos == 25
            System.out.println(XPos); //XPos == 70
        }

        plusButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isPlus) {
                    for (JTwinPreviewButtons subs : subButtons) {
                        subs.setSubShown(true);
                    }
                    plusButton.setText("-");
                    isPlus = false;
                    previewPanel.refresh();
                } else {
                    for (JTwinPreviewButtons subs : subButtons) {
                        subs.setSubShown(false);
                    }
                    plusButton.setText("+");
                    isPlus = true;
                    previewPanel.refresh();
                }
            }
        });

        itemButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        //here XPos == 70
        //after initialization method XPos == 25
    }
}

private void updateYPos() {
    YPos = overallYPos;
    overallYPos += 25;
}

private void setBounds() {
    updateYPos();
    System.out.println(XPos); //25
    plusButton.setBounds(XPos-20, YPos+2, 16, 16);
    itemButton.setBounds(XPos, YPos, itemButton.getText().length()*7+15, 20);
}

public void display() {
    if (shown) {
        System.out.println(XPos); //25
        setBounds();
        previewPanel.add(plusButton);
        previewPanel.add(itemButton);
    }
}
```

So, it would seem that XPos only retains its value for the duration of the initialization method. There are NO other places where XPos's value is set. What really confuses me about this is no matter what I set XPos to in the initialization it ALWAYS reverts to 25 yet I have scoured all of my code for any other spot where I mistakenly did "XPos = 25" and it simply does not exist in my code... What else could be at work here?

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PreviewPanel {
    ArrayList<JTwinPreviewButtons> topButtons = new ArrayList<JTwinPreviewButtons>();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);

    public PreviewPanel() {
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,750));
        refresh();
    }

    public void addTopButton(JTwinPreviewButtons button) {
        topButtons.add(button);
    }

    public void add(Component comp) {
        panel.add(comp);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        panel.removeAll();
        recursiveRefresh(topButtons);
    }

    private void recursiveRefresh(ArrayList<JTwinPreviewButtons> list) {
        for (JTwinPreviewButtons o : list) {
            o.display();
            recursiveRefresh(o.getSubButtons());
        }
    }

    public JPanel getComponent() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean `after initialization XPos = 25`?  where are you checking the value of `xpos` after you call your constructor?

Comment: `XPos = (itemNum * 15) + 25;`...are you creating your object with `itemNum == 0`?

Comment: @crush Doubtful, otherwise `25` would show up in debug printing too.

Comment: Do you have 3 sub buttons?

Comment: Jim Garrisson's answer is almost certainly correct, but can we see previewPanel's code to make sure

Comment: Adding to @RichardTingle 's comment, seeing where you're printing after initialization would help too.

Comment: @SamIam "after initialization XPos == 25" refers to any and all methods being called from this class when "System.out.println(XPos)" is add to them, print 25.

Comment: We need to see the code, unless you want us to answer "yes, java has gone mad"

Comment: @crush I think that is definitely the best question so far but alas, itemNum == 0 in only one case (which means that that is the only case not affected by this weird defaulting to 25)

Comment: @Hoodai any and all methods where?  so far you haven't indicated a specific call to `System.out.println(XPos)` that print's `25`.  You've told us about a `System.out.println(XPos);` that prints `25`, and you've vaguely said that it prints `25` after initialization, but until we see the path that actually prints `25` in your code, we can't give you a succinct answer.

Comment: @Hoodai The only thing that we can say is that the `JTwinPreviewButtons` that prints `70` and the `JTwinPreviewButtons` that prints `25` are almost certainly different instances of `JTwinPreviewButtons`

Comment: How does previewPanel get set to anything but null in JTwinPreviewButtons? I presume (as Sam I am suggests) that its a different JTwinPreviewButtons inside previewPanel

Comment: @RichardTingle previewPanel.refresh() the display() method of ALL JTwinPreviewButtons inside display() each JTwinPreviewButtons prints its own XPos

Comment: @RichardTingle JTwinPreviewButtons has a static reference to previewPanel that get set in the main method

Comment: @Hoodai Can we see that main method, and how you call this particular new JTwinPreviewButtons. http://sscce.org/ style would be excellent

Comment: Found it thanks to RichardTingle, SamIam, and especially crush. Give me a second to post in the answer what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that previewPanel was calling methods from JTwinPreviewButtons (JTPB). All of these methods when called from previewPanel would return X (the number of buttons) 25's. The reason for this was that the recursiveRefresh method was being called every time a new JTPB was created. Since previewPanel only had a reference to the top level JTPB it was calling that one's layout methods every time a new JTPB was created. That top one didn't actually have any references to the lower hierarchy JTPBs therefore the recursiveRefresh was not recursively affecting any other JTPBs.

Woooh that was crazy.

Answer (score 4):

The `XPos` referenced inside `JTwinPreviewButtons` is private to that class.  When you print `XPos` inside `previewPanel.refresh()` you are referring to a completely different variable.

Comment: I don't print it in previewPanel.refresh(). previewPanel has a reference to all JTwinPreviewButtons and when I set up a dummy method (inside JTwinPreviewButtons) to print their XPos, ALL of them print 25. Also, that doesn't explain why after initialization any methods called (where I can nest a System.out.print) print 25. Also, I have tried making it public previous to asking this question since that was my first suspicion of the culprit however, it resulted in the same outputs (25).

Comment: If you don't show the relevant code, how do you expect to get meaningful answers?

Comment: Updated ^ I was trying to post it but there is so much code and so many comments to respond to. I do not expect anyone to magically know the answer but posting more code takes a second.